# util.PSQLException: ERROR: column does not exist (problems with LEFT JOIN and @Formula)

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am writing `MVC` `Rest` online store. I use `Spring Boot`, `Hibernate` and `PostgreSQL` in my project. I have drinks and want to be able to sort them when I receive them. Everything works fine, the only thing I want to do is to take drinks if the order status is active. To do this, I added a `left join` query to my `sql`, and check it in the `PostgreSQL` console, everything worked. Only those drinks that were in the order with the active status were displayed. But if I throw the same `sql` query into *@Formula*, then an error is displayed. What could be the problem, and how do you use it?

My database schema:

[image]

Drink class with @FORMULA:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "drink")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Drink {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private BigDecimal price;

    /**
     * Drinks count in cart
     */
    @Formula("coalesce((select sum(c.count) from cart_items c" +
            " left join pg_order po on c.order_id = po.id" +
            " where order_status = 'ACTIVE' and\n" +
            "c.drink_id = id), 0)")
    private Long drinkCountInOrder;

    private String about;

    private int weight;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "packaging_id")
    private Packaging packaging;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "manufacturer_id")
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    private Country country;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Drink drink = (Drink) o;
        return isDeleted == drink.isDeleted &&
                Objects.equals(id, drink.id) &&
                Objects.equals(name, drink.name) &&
                Objects.equals(price, drink.price) &&
                Objects.equals(about, drink.about) &&
                Objects.equals(packaging, drink.packaging) &&
                Objects.equals(manufacturer, drink.manufacturer) &&
                Objects.equals(country, drink.country);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, price, about, isDeleted, packaging, manufacturer, country);
    }
}
```

Coffee class extends Drink:

```java
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "coffee")
public class Coffee extends Drink {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
    private CoffeeType coffeeType;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "roasting_id")
    private Roasting roasting;
}
```

Order class:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "pg_order")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String address;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_order")
    private Date dateOrder;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "order_status")
    private OrderStatus orderStatus;

    @Column(name = "total_cost")
    private BigDecimal totalCost;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<CartItem> cartItems = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Order{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", phoneNumber='" + phoneNumber + '\'' +
                ", dateOrder=" + dateOrder +
                ", orderStatus=" + orderStatus +
                ", totalCost=" + totalCost +
                ", user=" + user +
                ", cartItems=" + cartItems +
                '}';
    }
}
```

When I find all coffees, I am getting errors:

```java
2020-08-26 16: 03: 01.698 ERROR 8108 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: ERROR: column coffee0_1_.order_status does not exist
  Position: 487
2020-08-26 16: 03: 01.799 ERROR 8108 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] oaccC [. [. [/]. [DispatcherServlet]: Servlet.service () for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n / a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column coffee0_1_.order_status does not exist
  Position: 487
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse (QueryExecutorImpl.java:2532) ~ [postgresql-42.2.14.jar: 42.2.14]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults (QueryExecutorImpl.java:2267) ~ [postgresql-42.2.14.jar: 42.2.14]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute (QueryExecutorImpl.java:312) ~ [postgresql-42.2.14.jar: 42.2.14]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal (PgStatement.java:448) ~ [postgresql-42.2.14.jar: 42.2.14]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute (PgStatement.java:369) ~ [postgresql-42.2.14.jar: 42.2.14]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags (PgPreparedStatement.java:153) ~ [postgresql-42.2.14.jar: 42.2.14]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery (PgPreparedStatement.java:103) ~ [postgresql-42.2.14.jar: 42.2.14]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery (ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~ [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar: na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery (HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~ [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar: na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract (ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~ [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar: 5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet (Loader.java:2285) ~ [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar: 5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement (Loader.java:2038) ~ [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar: 5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement (Loader.java:2000) ~ [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar: 5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery (Loader.java:951) ~ [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar: 5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections (Loader.java:352) ~ [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar: 5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList (Loader.java:2831) ~ [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar: 5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList (Loader.java:2813) ~ [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar: 5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache (Loader.java:2645) ~ [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar: 5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list (Loader.java:2640) ~ [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar: 5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list (QueryLoader.java:506) ~ [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar: 5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list (QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~ [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar: 5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList (HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~ [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar: 5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list (SessionImpl.java:1412) ~ [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar: 5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList (AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565) ~ [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar: 5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list (AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533) ~ [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar: 5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList (Query.java:165) ~ [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar: 5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList (CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76) ~ [hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar: 5.4.17.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.readPage (SimpleJpaRepository.java:637) ~ [spring-data-jpa-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar: 2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll (SimpleJpaRepository.java:445) ~ [spring-data-jpa-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar: 2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll (SimpleJpaRepository.java:410) ~ [spring-data-jpa-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar: 2.3.1.RELEASE]
at java.base / jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method) ~ [na: na]
at java.base / jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~ [na: na]
at java.base / jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~ [na: na]
at java.base / java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566) ~ [na: na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke (ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72) ~ [spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar: 2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition $ RepositoryFragments.invoke (RepositoryComposition.java:382) ~ [spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar: 2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke (RepositoryComposition.java:205) ~ [spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar: 2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport $ ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke (RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549) ~ [spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar: 2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~ [spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke (QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155) ~ [spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar: 2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke (QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~ [spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar: 2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~ [spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke (DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~ [spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar: 2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~ [spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction (TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~ [spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke (TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~ [spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~ [spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke (PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~ [spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~ [spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor $ CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke (CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~ [spring-data-jELpa.java:178) ~ [spring-data-jELpa-2.3.1.RASEEEL.1]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~ [spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke (ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~ [spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~ [spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke (JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~ [spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy. $ Proxy151.findAll (Unknown Source) ~ [na: na]
at java.base / jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method) ~ [na: na]
at java.base / jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~ [na: na]
at java.base / jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~ [na: na]
at java.base / java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566) ~ [na: na]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection (AopUtils.java:344) ~ [spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke (JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~ [spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy. $ Proxy84.findAll (Unknown Source) ~ [na: na]
at ru.coffeetearea.service.CoffeeService.findAll (CoffeeService.java:107) ~ [main /: na]
at ru.coffeetearea.controller.CoffeeController.findAll (CoffeeController.java:71) ~ [main /: na]
at java.base / jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method) ~ [na: na]
at java.base / jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~ [na: na]
at java.base / jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~ [na: na]
at java.base / java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566) ~ [na: na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke (InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~ [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest (InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~ [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle (ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~ [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod (RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~ [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal (RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~ [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle (AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~ [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch (DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~ [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService (DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~ [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest (FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~ [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet (FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~ [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:634) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service (FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~ [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:741) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter (WsFilter.java:53) ~ [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy $ VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke (FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter (FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy $ VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter (ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy $ VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter (SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy $ VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter (AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy $ VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter (SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy $ VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter (RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy $ VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at ru.coffeetearea.security.jwt.JwtTokenFilter.doFilter (JwtTokenFilter.java:33) ~ [main /: na]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy $ VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter (LogoutFilter.java:116) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy $ VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter (HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal (HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~ [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy $ VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter (SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy $ VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal (WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~ [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy $ VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal (FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~ [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar: 5.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate (DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~ [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter (DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~ [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal (RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~ [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~ [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal (FormContentFilter.java:93) ~ [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~ [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal (CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~ [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~ [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar: 5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter (ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke (StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke (StandardContextValve.java:96) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke (AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke (StandardHostValve.java:139) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke (ErrorReportValve.java: 92) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke (StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service (CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service (Http11Processor.java:373) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process (AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol $ ConnectionHandler.process (AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint $ SocketProcessor.doRun (NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run (SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at java.base / java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~ [na: na]
at java.base / java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor $ Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~ [na: na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread $ WrappingRunnable.run (TaskThread.java:61) ~ [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar: 9.0.36]
at java.base / java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834) ~ [na: na]
```

P.S.I will once again write here that a query in the sql console is separately executed with the proper result.

PROBLEM QUERY IS IN DRINK CLASS

Comment: Where's the problem SQL query?

Comment: In Drink class field drinkCountInOrder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally wrote the formula incorrectly, making a syntax error there. I forgot to call the field via the table alias(po).

```java
@Formula("coalesce((select sum(c.count) from cart_items c" +
            " left join pg_order po on c.order_id = po.id" +
            " where po.order_status = 'ACTIVE' and\n" +
            "c.drink_id = id), 0)")
    private Long drinkCountInOrder;
```